# Extra mouse buttons with Raw Input API

Tags: winapi, mouse, raw-input

Im currently using RawInput to get mouse input, but it seems to not detect more than 3 buttons.  It says it has support for X1 and X2 as well, but none of my mice seem to trigger them.  Ive looked around, but Im not finding anything on google about how to use all the other mouse buttons.  If possible, Id like to find something that, like RawInput, can differentiate between multiple mice.  It seems like Im going to have to use rawinput with the HID setting, but I have no idea if theres a standard multi mouse button HID I can read or anything

Comment: may be you have some mouse driver software isntalled that captures the additional buttons to handle it different?

Comment: Does `GetRawInputDeviceInfo()` describe the extra buttons? What kind of button data is the `WM_INPUT` message actually providing to you? Can you provide an example?